# como ocultar tokens en un script python en github

Tags: python, github

Tengo un script de python en el cual utilizo unos token de telegram para realizar un bot.

Como puedo ocultar estos token en el repositorio de github?

les dejo la funcion con los token

```
def bot_send_text(bot_message):
    
    bot_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    bot_chatID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()
```

Comment: No puedes ocultarlo si lo subes al repo. Lo suyo es usar variables de entorno en tu rama local y no subirlas al remoto. Puedes usar [`python-dotenv`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) para este propósito. Saludos

Comment: tienes algo mas de informacion? cuando realizo el despliegue como el script encuentra los token?

Comment: ¿Cuando realizas el despliegue dónde? Tu pregunta es sobre ocultar el token en un repo de github, sobre configurar variables de entorno de producción, es otro tema. Debes configurar tus variables de entorno en el servidor donde hagas el despliegue. Para ello debes establecerlas con el mismo nombre que usas en tu script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es usar el paquete [`python-dotenv`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/), que te permitirá cargar variables locales desde un archivo de configuración `.env` local. El mismo no debes subirlo a tu repositorio (GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, etc.), y para ello has de añadirlo a tu archivo `.gitignore`.

De acuerdo a la documentación, la forma de usarlo sería la siguiente:

**Instalar la librería:**

```sh
pip install python-dotenv
```

Una vez que lo has instalado, lo importas en tu script:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()  # carga las variables de entorno desde el archivo .env.

#...
def bot_send_text(bot_message):
    
    bot_token = BOT_TOKEN         # <- variable de entorno
    bot_chatID = CHAT_ID          # <- variable de entorno
    bot_base_url = BOT_BASE_URI   # <- variable de entorno

    send_text = bot_base_url + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()
```

> Por defecto, `load_dotenv` no sobre escribe las variables de entorno existentes.
>
> Para configurar tu entorno de desarrollo local con las variables apropiadas, debes crear un archivo llamado `.env` en el directorio raíz de tu proyecto:
>
> ```sh
> .
> ├── .env
> ├── .gitignore
> └── foo.py
> ```

Dentro de este fichero debes escribir las variables de entorno que necesites y que sólo serán cargadas por `load_dotenv()` si el fichero `.env` existe y contiene dichas variables. Por ejemplo:

```sh
# Variables de entorno de desarrollo
BOT_TOKEN=BGex00bF3WEmvCb0i06ZKVzp5psTq7wl
CHAT_ID=529724
BOT_BASE_URI=https://api.telegram.org/bot
```

Debes añadir el fichero `.env` a la lista de `.gitignore`:

```sh
# Environments
.env
```

Puedes obtener una plantilla de `.gitignore` para Python desde [Python.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Python.gitignore) en Github.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

**EDICIÓN**

Tal como he leído de tus comentarios, no sabes cómo usar luego las variables de entorno en un despliegue de tu aplicación en Heroku.

El panel de administración de la aplicación de Heroku tiene una forma muy sencilla de hacerlo, simplemente debes entrar en el mismo, haciendo clic sobre la aplicación que deseas editar:

[image: Pantalla principal de Heroku]

Al abrir la aplicación, harás clic en *SETTINGS*:

[image: Clic en SETTINGS]

Una vez en la pestaña de *SETTINGS* vas a la sección *Config Vars* y haces clic en *Reveal Config Vars*:

[image: Reveal Config Vars]

Por último, puedes escribir las variables de entorno que tu aplicación utilizará. Estas variables estarán disponibles de forma global al desplegar tu aplicación, simplemente escribe el nombre de la variable y el valor en los campos adecuados, y para guardarla haz clic en el botón *ADD*:

[image: Añadir Variable de Entorno]

De esta forma las variables de entorno estarán seguras en tu aplicación y no tendrás que persistirlas en Github o ningún otro repositorio.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, y si realizó un despliegue del script en heroku como funcionaria los token?

Comment: @Daxtrox El panel de Heroku tiene una forma de configurar las variables de entorno para el despliegue de tu aplicación. Edito la respuesta para añadir esa información.